# Why those 3 fields don't get updated together?

Tags: angularjs

Following [this video tutorial](https://thinkster.io/egghead/the-dot), I am trying to bind three text inputs together.

But only the first get updated.

Here is [my JsFiddle attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/loloof64/44mxdahc/)

the index.html relevant part :

```
<body ng-app="">

    <input type="text" placeholder="Your text" ng-model="data.message"></input>
    <h2>{{data.message}}</h2>

    <div ng-controller="FirstController">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Your text" ng-model="data.message"></input>
         <h2>{{data.message}}</h2>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="SecondController">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your text" ng-model="data.message"></input>
        <h2>{{data.message}}</h2>
    </div>
</body>
```

script.js

```
function FirstController($scope){
}

function SecondController($scope){
}
```

What did I miss ?

Please also notice, that I do need the nested div tags and controller, as the purpose is to use scope inheritance.

Also, these global function definitions for the controllers are a choice, as I wanted to keep the video author method for now, in my real projects I will use the best practise which consist of using a module var controller() method).

Comment: is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/44mxdahc/1/

Comment: Not exactly : the video author explained that the nested div tags inherits from the root scope properties. And that's why we need the nested div tags and controller : in order to show this inheritance. But thank you for your purposition. Edited my question

Comment: just change script location(from onload event to not wrapped script): https://jsfiddle.net/44mxdahc/2/

Comment: this will create FirstController and SecondController in global context (window object), so angular would be able to find and instantiate those controllers

Comment: FYI, the ability to use global functions as controllers is [not recommended](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller#usage). You should use the `angular.module('myModule').controller('controllerName', function ControllerFn() { ... });` syntax instead. Preferably in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to avoid polluting the global scope.

Comment: Thank you, I know this better practise, but in order to be "synchronized" with the video tutorial, as it explains some stuffs I did not know, I decided to follow his way. (For example, I could not learn about scope inheritance when I was first told about controller() method of a module variable).

Comment: for this to work. you will have to use same version of angularjs, as the one used in the tutorial.. because from v1.3 global function as controllers do not work at all...

Comment: Thanks. Anyway the last version purposed by JsFiddle is 1.2.1 But really good remark.